# Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object line 11

Tags: php, mysqli

The issue is arising when I am trying to call the query; I don't see a problem with the logic of the code, but it still wants to throw an error. Line 11 is where the fetch_assoc() function is.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE url_short = '" . $short . "'") or die($mysqli->error);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
$Redir = filter_var($result, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

`$short` is set as a `$_GET` variable, whereas I've tried hard coding it in; to no avail.

Comment: You have `$mysqli->query()` so why are you doing `$query->fetch_assoc();`? Did you mean to do `$query = $mysqli->query()`? Or  `$result = $mysqli->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: Can we see the code before your query?

Comment: Use `$mysqli->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Using $mysqli instead of `$query` leaves me with a `Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Is `$mysqli` your `mysqli` connection? have you tried saving it to `$query = $mysqli->query(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it in wrong way -

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE url_short = '" . $short . "'");
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: OP is using OO style, not Procedural style, so connection is not needed. see the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Setting the $query variable before running the actual query seemed to have fixed the issue. Totally forgot that $query->fetch_assoc was reading from an actual query; had thought $query was defined in OOP as the returning query.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch from the variable `$query` which is not definied (at least in the code snipped you postet). Also you query into `$mysqli` and not into `$query`.

Try this one:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE url_short = '" . $short . "'") or die($mysqli->error);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

}
```